# Hibernate inserting two records for every create query for One to Many domain object

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a `Category` domain object that is intended to replicate a taxonomy term tree.  Due to some of the extra reference mappings, it was necessary for me to rewrite the object creation code.  The end result now is that Hibernate causes two data records to be inserted in the database for every `create()` execution.  One data record contains all NULL values, while the other contains the expected data.

My `Category` object:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(
    name="findCategoryByName",
    query="select category FROM Category c WHERE c.category = :category"
)
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "category_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String category;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Photo> photos= new ArrayList<>();;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Category parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Category> categoryList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Category() { }

    public Category(String category){
        this.category = category;
    }

    /* Other getters and setters */

}
```

The URL `localhost:8080/admin/category/create` hits this controller method with a POST request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = AdminRestURIConstants.CREATE_CATEGORY, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public Category createCategory(@RequestBody Category category){
    log.info("Start creating category " + category.getCategory());
    Category newCategory = categoryService.createCategory(category);
    return newCategory;
}
```

and this is my Repository override method for data insertions:

```
/**
 *
 * @param category
 * @return
 *
 * A Category object can be created with two types of parent references.  An Integer means the parent reference
 * exists, and the new Category will be added to the existing child set.  A String means the parent reference
 * is non-existing, and so two Category objects are made and bound.
 *
 * To maintain compatibility with the field settings of the Category domain model, an Integer value is passed in as a
 * String, and the execution of a parent update or create is made upon the thrown NumberFormatException when string-to-int
 * conversion fails.
 */
@Override
public Category create(Category category){
    try {
        int parentId = Integer.parseInt(category.getParent().getCategory());

        Category parent = super.findOne(parentId);
        category.setParent(parent);

        if (parent != null){
            parent.addCategory(category);
            update(parent);
        }
        else {
            throw new NumberFormatException();
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e){

        Category newParent = new Category(category.getParent().getCategory());
        newParent.addCategory(newCategory);
        newCategory.setParent(newParent);

        super.create(newParent);
    }

    super.create(newCategory);
    delete(category);
    return newCategory;
}
```

As of right now, if I pass in the ID of the parent Category as well as a String, the new Category gets added to the paren't `categoryList`.  However, a NULL record is also inserted:

```
{
    "id": 41,
    "category": "testCategory",
    "photos": null,
    "categoryList": [
        {
            "id": 42,
            "category": "newCategory",
            "photos": null,
            "categoryList": []
        },
        {
            "id": 83,
            "category": "newCategoryChild",
            "photos": null,
            "categoryList": []
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 42,
    "category": "newCategory",
    "photos": null,
    "categoryList": []
},
{
    "id": 82,
    "category": null,
    "photos": null,
    "categoryList": []
},
{
    "id": 83,
    "category": "newCategoryChild",
    "photos": null,
    "categoryList": []
}
```

As you can see, the category `newCategoryChild` is referenced within the `categoryList` array of `testCategory`.  However, prior to this record being created, a null object is being created.  This is also backed in the server logs:

```
Hibernate: select category0_.category_id as category1_0_1_, category0_.category as category2_0_1_, category0_.parent_category_id as parent3_0_1_, categoryli1_.parent_category_id as parent3_0_3_, categoryli1_.category_id as category1_0_3_, categoryli1_.category_id as category1_0_0_, categoryli1_.category as category2_0_0_, categoryli1_.parent_category_id as parent3_0_0_ from categories category0_ left outer join categories categoryli1_ on category0_.category_id=categoryli1_.parent_category_id where category0_.category_id=?
Hibernate: select categoryli0_.parent_category_id as parent3_0_1_, categoryli0_.category_id as category1_0_1_, categoryli0_.category_id as category1_0_0_, categoryli0_.category as category2_0_0_, categoryli0_.parent_category_id as parent3_0_0_ from categories categoryli0_ where categoryli0_.parent_category_id=?
Hibernate: insert into categories (category, parent_category_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into categories (category, parent_category_id) values (?, ?)
```

and the database:

```
mysql> select * from categories;
+-------------+------------------+--------------------+
| category_id | category         | parent_category_id |
+-------------+------------------+--------------------+
|          41 | testCategory     |               NULL |
|          42 | newCategory      |                 41 |
|          88 | NULL             |               NULL |
|          89 | newCategoryChild |                 41 |
+-------------+------------------+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

There are other posts here on SO about a simlar situation, but many of them are the result of unknown `merge` or `persist` calls.  I stepped through each method through the entire data insert process and the only `persist` or `merge` calls are directly from the repository code above.

Answer (score 1):

In your Repository  code "public Category create(Category category){}" method, it is clear that if parent is NULL, it will throw  new NumberFormatException(), later you catch the exception in your catch block and create the parent Category.After that, you create the the newCategory object. As you see, you have created two Objects,when parent is null,it will create (category NULL,parent_category_id NULL).

It is needed to point out that in your above method,there is no definition of newCategory(I assume it is declared in your class) and the last statement "delete(category)" is very confusing.

I suggest you review your code carefully.